# How to read a data struct sent serially from an arduino?

Tags: python, struct, arduino, serial-port

I'm struggling to read a binary data struct with Python3 sent serially from an Arduino Mega 2560.

***Arduino Code:***

```
char userInput;
bool ledState = false;

typedef struct 
{
  unsigned long  logTimeStart;
  unsigned long  frequencyOne;
  unsigned long  frequencyTwo;
  unsigned long  frequencyThree;
  unsigned long  frequencyFour;
  unsigned short int  revPowerOne;
  unsigned short int  revPowerTwo;
  unsigned short int  revPowerThree;
  unsigned short int  revPowerFour;
  unsigned short int  tempSensor; 
} SDLogger;

SDLogger dataLog;

void setup() 
{

  Serial.begin(9600);
  bitWrite(DDRB, 7, HIGH); // Set LED DDR high on port B, pin 7

  dataLog.logTimeStart = millis();
  dataLog.frequencyOne = 4000000000;       // PREDEFINED VALUES FOR TESTING
  dataLog.frequencyTwo = 4000000000;      
  dataLog.frequencyThree = 4000000000;
  dataLog.frequencyFour = 4000000000;
  dataLog.revPowerOne = 65000;             // PREDEFINED VALUES FOR TESTING
  dataLog.revPowerTwo = 65000;
  dataLog.revPowerThree = 65000;
  dataLog.revPowerFour = 65000;
  dataLog.tempSensor = 65000;

  Serial.println("<Arduino is ready>");
}

void loop() 
{
  checkForSerialMessage();
  delay(1000);
}

void checkForSerialMessage()
{
  Serial.println("checking serial...");
  if (Serial.available() > 0) 
  {
     userInput = Serial.read();

     if (userInput == 'a')
     {
      ledState = !ledState;
      bitWrite(PORTB, 7, ledState);
      Serial.println("led");    
     } 

     if (userInput == 'b')
     {
        Serial.write((byte*)&dataLog, sizeof(dataLog));
     }
  }
}
```

I believe the size of the struct is 30 bytes. My goal is to have the Arduino check the buffer intermittently for a specific character. When that character is received, the Arduino sends a defined data struct to my python interface, which is then unpacked and decoded into something readable by humans. I wrote an alternative command which toggles the Arduino's built-in LED. This was done to understand simple serial interfacing between the software. The LED toggle seems to function as expected, but not the struct commands.

**Python Code**

```
from tkinter import *
from struct import *
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
root = Tk() # root widget, this has to be first before any other widgets.

BINARY_STRFORMAT = "LLLLLHHHHH"         # Format to match arduino struct
print(calcsize(BINARY_STRFORMAT))       # RESULT IS 30

def toggleLED():
    ser.write(b'a')
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('ascii')  # readline functions will read until it sees a newline \n
                                                  #  .decode('ascii')
    print(arduinoData)

def toggleSerial():
    ser.write(b'b')
    arduinoData = ser.readline()
    print(arduinoData)
    unpacked = unpack(BINARY_STRFORMAT, arduinoData)


# in tkinter, everything is a widget:
header = Label(root, text="Read data from Arduino")
led_on = Button(root, text="led on", command=toggleLED)
read_serial = Button(root, text="enable data stream", command=toggleSerial)

# showing Label widget onto screen
header.pack()
led_on.pack()
read_serial.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

When I run the python code, I can use my rudimentary tkinter GUI to toggle the Arduino's LED. But when I attempt to request the data struct, I get a struct error:

```
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 30 bytes
```

I tried to read through the pySerial documentation to see if I could improve how my serial data is received, but I could not find struct references. I'm failing to understand how the struct is sent/received and how it should be read in python.

I'm relatively new to software engineering and serial communication, so please let me know if I need to clarify anything here.

Comment: What does the output of `print(arduinoData)` give?

Comment: print(arduinoData) in def toggleSerial() returns the struct.error message.

Comment: Don't know if it's possible to determine or display, but is the value of `sizeof(SDLogger)` in the Arduino C code equal to `30`?

Comment: Also, I'm wondering if the error comes from the arduino sending things like `"checking serial..."`, and so I wonder if `struct` is trying to load them instead... Can you try to send `a` and `b` from the arduino ide and check it works?

Comment: @martineau Yes, sizeof(SDLogger) and sizeof(dataLog) both return 30

Comment: @EdWard Yes, I can send `a` and `b` through the Arduino serial monitor. When I send `a`, I see the led toggle and a print statement of `led`. When I send `b`, I see binary data: ` (k⸮(k⸮(k⸮(k⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮`.

Comment: OK. I think the problem is trying to use `ser.readline()` to read the binary data—because it won't end with a newline (and it it did, there would be more than 30 bytes). Also, I think @EdWard meant to `print(arduinoData)` before trying to `unpack()` it. You might need to use `print(repr(arduinoData))`.

Comment: Okay, I think that makes sense and is reassuring to know. I suspected my problem had something to do with the pySerial, I'm just struggling to know how to parse that serial message with pySerial.

Comment: If you can successful get the binary data transmitted and received properly, using `struct` should work.

Comment: @martineau @Edward Update: I removed the Serial.print statements inside the arduino loop and function. I then reran the python and received this output:
`b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(k\xee\x00(k\xee\x00(k\xee\x00(k\xee\xe8\xfd\xe8\xfd\xe8\xfd\xe8\xfd\xe8\xfd'
(0, 4000000000, 4000000000, 4000000000, 4000000000, 65000, 65000, 65000, 65000, 65000)`
print(arduinoData) is the binary on the top line. and print(unpacked) is the struct.unpack result. I'm now getting exactly what I needed from the arduino onto python. Thank you both for your time and help.

Comment: @martineau It seemed like the Serial.print statements from the arduino interfered with the received data on python. Would either of you know how I could go about filtering that information out in the future? I ask because I foresee many more serial messages in the future coming from the arduino, I'd like to do the best I can to make sure the python GUI and arduino know when to listen/send data without running into this discrepency again.

Comment: Apparently `Serial.println()` is writing data to the same port you're trying to use to transmit and receive this other information on. You could probably define some simple protocol that allowed doing both without interfence — for example by defining an abstract variable-length `msg` structure with a header that identified the type of data being sent and its length, followed by the data itself). Once that is done you could write your own function to replace `println()`.

Answer (score 0):

Update: thanks to @martineau and @Edward, we learned that `Serial.println()` was writing data to the same port which was trying to transmit/receive the data struct. This overlap was interfering with the python GUI's ability to parse and decode the binary struct. When the `Serial.println()` was removed, the python GUI received the expected 30-byte struct.